# Allow SMTP AUTH only from mynetworks

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to allow SMTP AUTH only from IPs in mynetworks? I've tested a bunch of options but no one worked. Here's the actual state of my main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mx1.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 172.20.1.0/24 172.18.1.0/24 192.168.0.0/24 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/blocked-recipients.cf,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

message_size_limit = 409600000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @84104. Your answer led me to find [this topic](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/smtpd-sasl-exceptions-networks-doesn-t-work-tp75290.html) which solved my problem.

> `smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks` does not announce AUTH support but still allows AUTH from any IP.
>
> This feature was donated to prevent certain network clients from
>   messing  up when the server announces AUTH support but the client has
>   no  login information. With `smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks`, those
>   clients  would not try to authenticate and all was well.
>
> `smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks` is obsoleted by
>   **[`smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords)**  and
>   **[`smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps)**. The latter two prevent 
>   Postfix from accepting AUTH commands.
>
> `smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks` should probably be deprecated and
>   eventually removed from documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You'll likely want to use [`smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks).